Felt VR40 - 2020
Hi everyone I'm looking for information's on how to adapt my Felt VR40 [baught in 2020] into a gravel bike.
Current configuration
Frameset

FrameFelt VR 3.0, SuperLite aluminum
ForkFelt VR 3.0, UHC Advanced carbon

Brakes & Drivetrain

Front brake Shimano BR-4770, 2-piston, Hydraulic disc brake
Front brake rotorShimano SM-RT70, 160 mm, Center lock
Rear brakeShimano BR-4770, 2-piston, Hydraulic disc brake
Rear brake rotorShimano SM-RT70, 140 mm, Center lock
Rear derailleurShimano Tiagra, RD-4700, 20-S
front derailleurShimano Tiagra, FD-4700
CassetteShimano CS-HG500, 11-34 T
ChainShimano CN-HG54
CranksetShimano Tiagra, FC-4700, 50/34 T
Shift leverShimano Tiagra, ST-4720

Wheels

WheelsetDevox WheelRDS.A1, Tubeless ready, Center lock, 12x100/12x142 mm
TireSchwalbe Lugano II, 700x32

Cockpit

StemDevox StemR.A2
54 cm: IS (NO.42)
Handlebar43, 47 cm: Devox DBar.A2 31.8 mm, 380 mm,
54 cm: Devox DBar.A2 31.8 mm, 420 mm


The biggest difference between gravel bikes and road bikes is that gravel bikes have wider tyres. It looks like officially your bike has clearance for 34mm wide tyres while gravel bikes usually have clearance for at least 40mm.
You’ll probably be able to exceed it slightly and use 35mm wide tyres. This is the narrowest gravel tyre size and would allow you to mount tyres like a Schwalbe G-One or Continental Terra Speed.
On hard ground the small lugs of a gravel tyre won’t make much of a difference compared to the smooth 32mm road bike tyres you have right now.
I’d try riding the bike in it’s current state with a lower tyre pressure (as low as you can go without suffering pinch flats) and see how satisfied you are. If it feels very uncomfortable and unsafe on gravel and other “off-road” surfaces, going to 35mm gravel tyres won’t make enough of a difference for you to be happy.

To this point, prior to circa 2014, folks in the Pacific Northwest of the US seemed content to put 32 mm tires on “endurance” road bikes and ride gravel.

@PaulH: Yes, cyclocross bikes also still have a 33mm limit in UCI races. It kind of depends on what one wants to do with the bike. I wouldn’t want to ride rough gravel on ≤35mm tyres for hours on end.

@PaulH: Yeah, one is tempted to suggest "Ride on gravel". But I try to resist temptation.

@DanGao * "Ride on gravel".
